# Anime with character who has markings/balls on his arm that allow him to operate weapons

Tags: story-identification, anime

I saw an anime on toonamai about about a guy (who I believe was an orphan) who kept breaking through doors to get to another realm.

Something happens, and he does get through, but now he has markings on his left arm with strange little balls that stick out that can be placed into weapons (and stuff) to make them work. They can summon giant beings, but only a select few can.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! These might help you to improve your question; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and [How to ask a good (anime) Story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question/11875#11875)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the anime you are looking for is called Kiba.
Kiba is a shard caster that travels to a different realm by breaking down a door/gate. Once in that realm he has markings show up on his arm and they contain 3 shards that look like half orbs. He inserts these shards into a tool which then produces an energy blade. The only point that I not positive about is the giant summoning.

Comment: Can you explain why you think this anime fits the description given?

Comment: [Here, a video](https://youtu.be/Yhc-sFBduRY?t=19m10s)