# Old anime show with a guy with red orbs in his arms that summon things

Tags: story-identification, anime

I watched this anime quite some time ago. I've been trying to find it for a few months because I never finished it.

It started with this boy/guy who is in a metro city kind of setting. He goes through this portal that takes him to some world that summon creatures out of orbs. The thing is he had 3 red orbs in his arms that bring out fire creatures.

Comment: Any chance is it a Pokemon show? Red orbs with monsters in them?

Comment: Could it be [Kiba](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yhc-sFBduRY&feature=youtu.be&t=19m10s)? If so, this is a duplicate of [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/190007/4495).

Comment: @MrLister could very well be Kiba indeed; post it as an answer :)

Comment: @Jenayah Will that help? The OP here hasn't returned since asking; so it's unlikely they will come back to accept.

Comment: @MrLister it's up to you, but I can see several pros - future readers don't have to be redirected to another question, this question gets a proper answer and not just "your anime is in another castle", you get some rep and story-id answer out of it so everybody wins :)

Answer (score 4):

I hear red orbs summoning in a different dimension and I think [Bakugan](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1114855/). It's another spin on the pokemon/digimon/beyblade/yu-gi-oh/... idea of having a game be the one thing that governs people's lives, including bad guys also using it to try to take over the world.

In this one, players have both little balls and cards. Fights begin by both players flipping over a card dramatically, which transports them and any plot related allies to a pocket-dimension. A turn (sometimes) consists of throwing down one of your cards to (sometimes) join up with cards already in play. These cards form the battlefield for your 'Bakugan', which are small orbs, which you have to throw on top of the battlefield. In some episodes it's important which card they land on, in others it doesn't matter at all. These orbs then transform into large monsters, which (sometimes) fight the opponent's monsters in the same square, (sometimes) receiving bonuses from the cards the fight takes place on.

The abundance of sometimes in the previous paragraph is explained by the larger than usual inconsistency in the rules for fights throughout each episode of the anime.

Answer (score 3):

[Kiba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kiba_(TV_series))

The main characrer's name is Zed, and he summons "Amil Gaoul" this angel thing that's super strong

He does not have red orbs in his arm, but he does have blue orbs.

[image: Image of Zed showing the orbs in his arm]

Comment: Does Zed have red orbs in his arms? If he does, you should [edit] your answer to reflect that.