# Cartoon where monsters are captured by wrist devices, turned into orbs, merged, and used for battle

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

It’s a show where they use wrist things that launch 3 pronged claws from their wrist area to capture and when captured the monster turn into orbs. They merge them and send them to battle. The MC worked for a battle team were he was being bullied and then a evil org manifest to merge 3 monsters into one.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Is this an animated show? And in roughly which year did you watch it? Also, what do you mean by an "evil org?" An evil organisation?

Comment: Maybe but relevant, but https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/198036/23243 has monsters captured into orbs on the wrist. Suggested (but disputed) answer of *Bakugan*.

Answer (score 5):

This is almost definitely *[Battleclaw](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt7661510/)*. Wrist launchers that shoot a claw. Combining caught creatures(in this case they make dual affinity or triple affinity later).

From [TVTropes](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/WesternAnimation/Battleclaw):

> Battleclaw is the story of a boy named Tyee (Pronounced "Tie-yee") who aspires to Be The Very Best at the eponymous Battleclaw, a sport that involves catching colorful creatures called Jinlins using an Energy Grappler and then Combining them into one, dual-attribute monster who then does battle with other Battleclaw players.
>
> After his uncle reneges on his promise to let him join his own team, Tyee winds up with a Ragtag Bunch of Misfits called Team Gogo after pulling a Legendary Battleclaw from a stone.
>
> Tyee had better hone his skills, because the Battleclaw of the Ancient Fire Lord Mo Yan recently fell into the hands of his uncle, and the Ghost of Mo-Yan demands the power of the Jinlins in order to regain his former power! It's up to Tyee and the rest of Team Gogo to stop Mo Yan from returning to life!

Answer (score 2):

From your description, my 18 year old son believes it to Digimon:

A group of young teens is unexpectedly sent to the mysterious Digital World and paired up with their own powerful, morphing monster called the Digimon. Together the entire group set out on an adventure to fight evil and save the world.

Comment: Capturing creatures and then battling with them in a quest to save the world is a collection of very common tropes. Can you address the *specifics* here (orbs, combining creatures, three tentacles capturing the monsters, etc)?

Comment: Also, when quoting a text from another site, please provide a link to the relevant web page, and type `>` before the first word in each quoted paragraph, so that it'll be highlighted as a quote.